# How to resolve "can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK" error with pre-compiled Azure Function?

Tags: .net, azure, f#, .net-core, azure-functions

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 class library of pre-compiled Azure Functions. When I run them locally with the CLI, everything runs fine. Storage bindings are done via attributes.

After publishing to Azure via CLI, I only receive this cryptic error when trying to run an HTTP Triggered function:

```
{
  "id": "4de8aa2a-73cf-4978-8aef-492310858379",
  "requestId": "03f813ea-0390-4262-a44d-f6646cb96e68",
  "statusCode": 500,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "'[Function Name]' can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK. Is it missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes?"
}
```

How can I figure out what this is asking for? I have no idea if it's something in my code or something I need to configure in the function app.

Comment: What is the generated function.json? This should be in your output folder.  For Precompiled, the client-side tooling will reflect over the compiled assembly and generated function.json files, which then get sent to the server. The next step in diagnosing this is looking at those generated files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the function app runtime version option to `beta` (Runtime version: 2.0.11415.0) seems to get my function apps working

Comment: Do you know how to change this using VS2017, I'm developing locally and trying test but running into similar error

Comment: This was in the azure portal settings for the function app, not in VS.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same error today when I was trying to call my Negotiate Function from an Angular client. When I looked at the trace, I was getting a different error as below.

> Error indexing method 'NegotiateFunction.Run' [12/31/2018 9:33:41 AM]
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
>   'NegotiateFunction.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind
>   parameter 'info' to type AzureSignalRConnectionInfo. Make sure the
>   parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding
>   extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure
>   you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your
>   startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(),
>   builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

I understood that the problem is with my old packages and updated the below packages.

[image]

After that, I was able to build my Azure Function and the call to Negotiate function was successful.

[image]